# Continuous surjective map on a path connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$ which induces a covering map on a deformation retract space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, covering-spaces, retraction

Let $A \subseteq B$ be path connected subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, $n\ge 2$. Let $i:A \to B$ be the inclusion map  and $r:B \to A$ be a deformation retraction i.e. $r\circ i=id_A$ and $i\circ r$ is homotopic to $id_B$ i.e. $A$ is a deformation retract of $B$.

Let $p: B \to B$ be a surjective continuous function such that $p(A)=A$ and $p|_A:A \to A$ is a covering map. Then is $p:B \to B$ also a covering map ?

Comment: Take $A=\{0\}$, $B=\mathbb{D}$ and $p:B\to B$, such that $p$ is identity on $B(0,1/2)$; it maps $B(0,3/4)\setminus \overline{B(0,1/2)}$ linearly radially to $B(0,1/2)\setminus \overline{B(0,1/4)}$; and $B(0,1)\setminus \overline{B(0,3/4)}$ to $B(0,1)\setminus \overline{B(0,1/4)}$ in a continuous way.

Comment: @deb : "linearly radially" ... could you be a little more explicit ?

Comment: Is it better if I say radial line segments to radial line segments, fixing the end points so that the map is continuous?

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $A = \{0 \}, B = \mathbb R^2 = \mathbb C$. Then $p(z)  = z^2$ is a continous surjection, but no covering map.